# How can I avoid re-triggering a django signal?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I have this signal and I want it to not run once it has already checked each instance once, currently it falls into an infinite recursion loop since it triggers itself each time it runs.

```
from django.db.models.signals import (
    post_save,
)
from django.dispatch import receiver
from app.models import (
    QuestionForm,
    Question,
)


@receiver(post_save, sender=form)
def get_max_score(
        sender: form,
        instance: form,
        **kwargs: dict,
) -> None:
    forms = form.objects.all()
    for form in forms.iterator():
        total = 0
        questions = form.questions.all()
        for item in questions.iterator():
            total += item.points
        form.set_score(total)
        form.save()
```

Any help is appreciated, bonus points if the answer is less complex than n^2.

Edit: this is the form model itself:

```
class QuestionForm(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    questions = models.ManyToManyField(
        Question,
        related_name='questions'
    )

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        editable=False,
    )

    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True,
        editable=False,
    )

    max_score = models.IntegerField(
        default=0,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_score(self):
        return self.max_score

    def set_score(self, score):
        self.max_score = score
```

Comment: I would actually advice simply not storing the `score` in the `form` items, that will not only make it a lot easier to save it, but also more efficient and more reliable.

Comment: Can you share the models and *what* you aim to achieve?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem I'm afraid I do need the max_score saved in the form model, since it is required whenever someone answers it, instead of calculating it each time someone sends a response and querying each question in the form.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise *not* to store the score in the `form` objects. Indeed, not only will this avoid the problem with the signals: we can do this more efficient at the database side, and only when we *need* the score, and also make it more robust.

Signals are often a bad idea. Indeed, signals can be circumventing, for example with a [**`.bulk_create(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) that will not trigger signals for created objects. There are also a lot of scenarios where the data can change: creating records, updating records, removing records. It turns out that keeping the same data in sync, even on the same database, is not easy. I summarized some problems with signals in [*this article* <sup>[django-antipatterns]</sup>](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html).

Therefore it might be better to just omit the `score`:

```
class QuestionForm(models.Model):
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(
        Question,
        related_name='questions'
    )
    # …
    # no score field
    pass


class Question(models.Model):
    points = models.IntegerField()
```

Now if we want the `Form`s with the corresponding score for the related `Question`s, we can use:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

QuestionForm.objects.annotate(score=Sum('questions__points'))
```

The `Form`s that arise from this `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `.score` that will contain the sum of the `.points` of the *related* `Question`s. If the queryset is filtered down, it will also not aggregate the ones we don't need, and since the aggregate is done by the database, that is usually quite efficient.

---

> **Note**: The [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so from the `Question` model to the `QuestionForm`
> model in this case. Therefore it (often) makes not much sense to name it the
> same as the forward relation. You thus might want to consider renaming the <s>`questions`</s> relation to `forms`.

Comment: That sounds great but how would I reference the score attribute? "Form.score" isn't working.

Comment: @Grimidk: if you use the annotated queryset: `for form in queryset: print(form.score)`.

Comment: that did the trick after defining the queryset and filtering to only match the one I'm currently checking just like you said.